# Join two dataframes, sum up the values and get the maximum

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two .txt data files. The first contains two columns (movie, cinema) and the second one also contains two columns (movie, viewers), as shown in the example below. What I want to do, is to **find the movie that was shown in `cinema_1` with the maximum number of audience.**

```
+----------+---------+
| movie    |  cinema |
+----------+---------+
| movie_1 | cinema_2 |
| movie_2 | cinema_3 |
| movie_4 | cinema_1 |
| movie_3 | cinema_1 |
+------+-------------+

+----------+---------+
| movie    | viewers |
+----------+---------+
| movie_1 |    10    |
| movie_2 |    98    |
| movie_4 |    100   |
| movie_3 |    19    |
| movie_1 |    340   |
| movie_3 |    31    |
+------+-------------+
```

i.e. in the example above, the two candidates are `movie_3` and `movie_4` (shown in cinema_1) and the correct answer is `movie_4` with 100 views (while `movie_3` has 50 (19+31) views).

What I've done so far:

**Step 1:** Get the data

```
    val moviesCinemas = sparkSession.read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
        .load("moviesCinemas.txt");

    val moviesViewers = sparkSession.read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
        .load("moviesViewers.txt");
```

**Step 2:** Get the movies shown in `cinema_1`

```
val cinema1Movies = moviesCinemas.filter(col("cinema").like("cinema_1"))
```

leading to:

```
+----------+---------+
| movie    |  cinema |
+----------+---------+
| movie_4 | cinema_1 |
| movie_3 | cinema_1 |
+------+-------------+
```

**Step 3:** Now for those two movies I have to sum up their viewers (from dataframe `moviesViewers`) and report the one with the maximum number. This is where I am actually stuck.

I've tried to join the `cinema1Movies` and `moviesViewers` dataframes

```
val joinMoviesViewers = moviesViewers.join(cinema1Movies, Seq("movie"))
```

that gives the following result:

```
+----------+---------+
| movie    | viewers |
+----------+---------+
| movie_4 |    100   |
| movie_3 |    19    |
| movie_3 |    31    |
+------+-------------+
```

Now I am not quite sure how to sum up the `viewers` for each `movie` in order to get something like this (and finally get the movie with the max viewers):

```
+----------+---------+
| movie    | viewers |
+----------+---------+
| movie_4 |    100   |
| movie_3 |    50    |
+------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the joined data frame:

```
val aggJoin = joinMoviesViewers.groupBy("movie").agg(sum($"viewers").as("viewers"))
// aggJoin: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [movie: string, viewers: bigint]

val maxViewers = aggJoin.agg(max($"viewers")).first().getLong(0)
// maxViewers: Long = 100

// depending on what data type you have for viewers, you might use getDouble here
// val maxViewers = aggJoin.agg(max($"viewers")).first().getDouble(0)

aggJoin.filter($"viewers" === maxViewers).show
+-------+-------+
|  movie|viewers|
+-------+-------+
|movie_4|    100|
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: It works, but instead of `.getLong(0)` add `.getDouble(0)`. Otherwise you'll get an Exception. Please edit your answer in order to accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The below is the API approach to derive the result.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val result = moviesCinemas
  .filter($"cinema" === "cinema_1" )
  .join(moviesViewers, "movie")
  .select(moviesCinemas("movie"),moviesViewers("viewers"))
  .groupBy($"movie")
  .agg(sum($"viewers").as("sum_cnt"))
  .orderBy($"sum_cnt".desc)

  result.first
  res34: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [movie_4,100]
```

The below uses spark sql to get the same result.

```
moviesCinemas.registerTempTable("movies_cinemas")
moviesViewers.registerTempTable("movies_viewers")

val spark = SparkSession.builder.
  master("local") // set your master here
  .appName("spark session example")
  .getOrCreate()

val result = spark.sql( 
"""
SELECT 
t0.movie,
sum(viewers) as total_viewers
FROM
movies_cinemas t0 JOIN movies_viewers t1
on t0.movie = t1.movie 
WHERE t0.cinema = "cinema_1"
GROUP BY t0.movie
ORDER BY total_viewers desc
"""
)

result.first

res6: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [movie_4,100]
```